# Send same value to two hidden fields onchange

Tags: forms, select, onchange, drop-down-menu

I'm having difficulty passing the same value to two hidden fields. So for example, if I select Product 1, I want both hidden fields to have a value of X.

```
<select>
<option value="X">Product 1</option>
<option value="Y">Product 2</option>
<option value="Z">Product 3</option>
</select>
<input id="test" name="product_id[]" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="test" name="product_id" type="hidden" value="">
```

I've tried using onchange methods, but I can only pass a single value only one of the hidden fields, not both.

Here is what I tried, granted I was using the same id for both fields which I realize now won't work.

```
<form action="../index.php" method="post" >     
 <div id="Select">
          <select id="myselect" onchange="this.form.prodhid.value=this.selectedIndex">
    <option>Please Select an Amount</option>
             <option value="1">Product 1</option>
            <option value="2">Product 2</option>
            <option value="3">Product 3</option>
    </select>    
     <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" id="prodhid" value="" />
     <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="prodhid" value="" />
<input value="Add to Cart" title="Add to Cart" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you pass the value to hidden fields ie your onChange method?

Comment: Sure, I updated the code in my original post

Answer (score 0):

You can't access two DOM elements with the same id. So you may change your markup to something like this

```
<input id="test1" name="product_id[]" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="test2" name="product_id" type="hidden" value="">
```

Or you can try something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function change()
      {
        var list = document.getElementById('test-group')
                           .getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
          list[i].value = 'X';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <select onchange="change()">
      <option value="X">Product 1</option>
      <option value="Y">Product 2</option>
      <option value="Z">Product 3</option>
    </select>
    <div id="test-group">
      <input name="product_id[]" type="hidden" value="">
      <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```